# Python regex not returning as expected

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing some text with Python and am running into an odd issue...

an example text that is being parsed:

> msg:"ET WEB_SPECIFIC_APPS ClarkConnect Linux proxy.php XSS Attempt"; flow:established,to_server; content:"GET"; content:"script"; nocase; content:"/proxy.php?"; nocase; content:"url="; nocase; pcre:"//proxy.php(?|.*[\x26\x3B])url=[^&;\x0D\x0A]*[<>"']/i"; reference:url,www.securityfocus.com/bid/37446/info; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2010602; classtype:web-application-attack; sid:2010602; rev:4; metadata:created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2010_07_30;

my regex:

`msgSearch = re.search(r'msg:"(.+)";",line)`

actual result:

> ET WEB_SPECIFIC_APPS ClarkConnect Linux proxy.php XSS Attempt"; flow:established,to_server; content:"GET"; content:"script"; nocase; content:"/proxy.php?"; nocase; content:"url="; nocase; pcre:"//proxy.php(?|.*[\x26\x3B])url=[^&;\x0D\x0A]*[<>"']/i

expected result:

> ET WEB_SPECIFIC_APPS ClarkConnect Linux proxy.php XSS Attempt

There are 10s of thousands of lines of text that I am parsing that are all giving me similar results. Any reason regex is picking a (seemingly) random `";` to stop at? I can fix the example above by making the regex more specific, eg. `r'msg:"([\w\s\.]+)";"` but other lines have different characters included. I guess I *could* just include every special character in my regex, but I'm trying to understand why my wildcard isn't working properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With your shown samples please try `\bmsg:\"([^\"]+)\"` regex Online demo is https://regex101.com/r/U6ASno/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python regex first/shortest match](/q/11301387/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
re.search(r'msg:"([^;]+)";',line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.+` is by default "greedy", i.e. it will match as many characters as possible. In your case, it will stop at the **last** `";` sequence, not at the **next** one. To make it non-greedy (or lazy), try `.+?` :

```
 msgSearch = re.search(r'msg:"(.+?)";",line)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation about ```.+``` being greedy! for some reason, ```(.+?)``` returned an empty string :( but the other examples of using the "everything except" regex (```([^;]+)``` and ```([^\"]+)```) worked out.